# Retrieve Username from User ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, show, relationships

Hi I have a posts model where a post belongs_to a user and a user has_many posts.

The posts table has a user_id

At the moment in my show posts I have:

```
<td><%= post.user_id %></td>
```

I get the users id who makes the post this works fine. How can I get the username when the Users table contains a column User_name do I need to add post_id to Users or?

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
 :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :username, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

 has_one :profile
 has_many :orders
has_many :posts

end

  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    attr_accessible :content, :title, :user_id
    validates :title, presence: true,
                length: { minimum: 5 }
 end
```

In my posts controller I have

```
def create
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
@post.user_id = current_user.id
respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
 end
```

Comment: if you have no client actually paying for a webservice api, take those format.json lines out. They are just for tutorials; real projects should never have excess speculative code

Answer (score 3):

If `post` `belongs_to` `user` then you can do:

```
<%= post.user.user_name %>
```

And no you don't need to add `post_id` to Users because it's the `post` that `belongs_to` `user` not `user` `belongs_to` `post`.  When `post` `belongs_to` `user`, you have `user_id`,  foreign key in `posts` table.

Hope this makes sense.

**Update:**

The reason you are getting `undefined method 'username' for nil:NilClass` is because the way you are creating post is not attaching the associated `user` object.  Since you are using `devise` here is what you can do to make this work:

```
# app/controllers/posts.rb

def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
  # @post.user_id = current_user.id # Remove this line
  ...
end
```

I'm not including the irrelavant lines in `create` action above.

The `current_user.posts.build(params[:post])` builds a `post` object for the `current_user`, this way the built `post` gets the associated user in this case `current_user`.  With this you will be able to do:

```
post.user.username
```

Comment: I get this error when I try that undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Shouldn't it be `user_name` and not `username`?  Note the underscore.

Comment: Its username in mine sorry I made a mistake in my first post

Comment: Can you post your `user` and `post` model and the controller's action that renders the view in question.

Comment: Updated my first post with them

Comment: Which Rails version are you using, are posts being created?  Can you create a post for an user from the console?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43294/discussion-between-vinodadhikary-and-user2527785)