# Rails - How to find single record (user name) show it in Home page to any visitors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

On a rails 5.1.6 project with BS4 and using Devise, I am trying to solve the following issue.

I am trying to display the name of the user who owns a project in Home page.  This does not work.  It returns a name error: undefined local variable or method `user'

Controllers are the following:

Project controller:

```
def create
   @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
end
```

The home page controller shows as follows:

```
def home
 @projects = Project.where(publish: true).limit(8)
end
```

If I am trying to add to the pages controller
    @users = User.find(params[:user_id])
It does not work. (Record not found/ Couldn't find User with 'id'=)

The (truncated) view is the following:

```
    <div class="card-row border-top d-flex">
      <div class="card2-post__author d-flex">
          <img class="card2-project-author-avatar"
        <%= image_tag avatar_url(@user), class: "avatar-small" %></img>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center ml-3">
          <span class="card2-project-author-name"><%= user.fullname %></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

That view is in a partial with is rendered in two instances:

a) under a user dashboard with:

```
<%= render partial: "projects/projects_list", locals: {user: current_user, projects: @projects} %>
```

the controller for the user shows:

```
def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @projects = @user.projects
end
```

This is working.

b) the second

```
<%= render partial: "projects/projects_list", locals: {user: current_user, projects: @projects} %>
```

This one does not work whatever I try. I get a feeling of where to look for but I seem to be stuck without ideas and would appreciate the help that will point me to the solution or a methodology to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a comment:
i have solved things to a certain extent by adding :

def home
   @user = current_user
   ....
   end

and changing the call on partial to: 

    <%= render partial: "rooms/rooms_list", locals: {rooms: @rooms} %>
I am surprised this is the solution (I thought I had tried it before posting...).  I m still interested by a methodology to debug things, if any.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by adding :fullname to params in the create controller.  The following has guided me through:  [Retrieve Username from User ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622630/retrieve-username-from-user-id)

```
def create
  ...
  @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
  ...
end

private
  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(...:fullname)
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first error:

```
undefined local variable or method `user'
```

probably is caused by missing `@` in your partial:

```
<span class="card2-project-author-name"><%= user.fullname %></span>
```

Once the user is signed into an app with Devise, you have an access to that user by calling `current_user` method. There is no need to fetch the user from the database again (by calling `User.find...`). You can save the user object in the instance variable like this:

```
@user = current_user
```

Comment: Thanks. understood. fighting unnecessary db traffic is a design objective. A logged in user trying to access the view trigger a mistake because of the current_user.  How should I adjust current_user to permit the visitor to see that data without triggering an error ?